# Angular: ng-repeat returns incorrect output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uikit, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been looking for answers for this problem for a while, but I just don't have enough knowledge to find the solution, so you are my last resort.

For this one page app I'm using AngularJS and UiKit.
I have a list of "Shipments" that when displayed statically looks like this:

[image]

and here's the code fragment for each box:

```
<div class="uk-width-large-1-5 uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-width-small-1-2 uk-text-center">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-container-center uk-panel-header uk-panel-box-primary">
        <h4 class="uk-panel-title"><i class="uk-icon-truck">&nbsp;Shipment 4</i></h4>
        <i class="uk-icon-plus-square uk-icon-small uk-text-success" data-uk-tooltip title="Created on 27/09/2014"></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-square uk-icon-small uk-text-warning" data-uk-tooltip title="Scanning in progres..."></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-phone-square uk-icon-small uk-hidden" data-uk-tooltip title="Reference added on 31/09/2014"></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-pencil-square uk-icon-small uk-hidden" data-uk-tooltip title="Invoice generated on 01/10/2014"></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-external-link-square uk-icon-small uk-hidden" data-uk-tooltip title="Dispatched on 01/10/2014"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I'm using ng-repeat, it renders incorrectly, like this:

[image]

```
<div ng-repeat="shipment in shipments | orderBy:'createdAt':true" id="shipment.id" class="uk-width-large-1-5 uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-width-small-1-2 uk-text-center">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box uk-container-center uk-panel-header">
        <h4 class="uk-panel-title"><i class="uk-icon-truck">&nbsp;{{ shipment.reference }}</i></h4>
        <i class="uk-icon-plus-square uk-icon-small uk-text-success" data-uk-tooltip title="{{ shipment.createdAt }}"></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-square uk-icon-small uk-text-warning" data-uk-tooltip title="Scanning in progres..."></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-phone-square uk-icon-small uk-hidden" data-uk-tooltip title="Reference added on 31/09/2014"></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-pencil-square uk-icon-small uk-hidden" data-uk-tooltip title="Invoice generated on 01/10/2014"></i>
        <i class="uk-icon-external-link-square uk-icon-small uk-hidden" data-uk-tooltip title="Dispatched on 01/10/2014"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see both snippets are very similar as the second one is based on the first one.

Hopefully someone will be able to help me with that.

Comment: May be an obvious question...did you check if you were pushing the same item into shipments collection multiple times in your controller code??

Comment: Hello, at the moment the controller pulls all items from Shipments collection and that's what is displayed with ng-repeat, however all  objects have different id's and are stored as separate (they only share common name, it's just for development).

Comment: I see.. so your problem is that the spacing between the rows is missing. Right??

Comment: Exactly, even if it's not missing in static code (if I'm doing any changes, like hide and show the div container, it re-aligns itself to correct spacing, which is even more strange :P).

Comment: AngularJS has this scope based problem you might have hit that... Try to put the shipments in an object so that you'll access it like `shipment in someName.shipments`

Comment: To me it seems more of a style that you might be missing. Try adding one class at a time and find which one caused that space to go. I see that you are not using "uk-panel-box-primary" in the second example but using in the first. It could be a problem. You might be to try it by trial and error.

Comment: Forgive me for being ignorant, but do you mean to put the whole array as an object's attribute? Because I'm not sure how to do that  in Angular (is it in service?)

Comment: uk-panel-box-primary doesn't change anything, however removing all <i> tags and putting anything else in there (like just text) seems to fix the problem. But even if, I have no way of placing them back to make them work.

Comment: If taking out the images seems to work,..it seems like its more of a UIKit issue than Angular scope issue. Compare the dom for both cases and compare the styles (paddings, etc) being set.

Comment: I'll go throught that, however if it's not related to Angular, why is the static version working ok? Strange indeed :P

Comment: Good point...the only thing I can think of is the values are different in your static version vs angular version. Since the last three images you are using are not using angular, take them out from both static and angular versions to make it easier to find what the problem is.

Comment: That's what I did now, separated both versions to be exclusive. Is there something about ng-repeat in a way it renders html that it can strip or omit something?

Comment: You really should make the HTML the same, in your case in one example the class `uk-panel-box-primary` is missing